# react Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: reactjs, fetch, setstate

I keep getting this error:
**TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance**
 while I'm trying to fetch some data in here :

```
export const genres = () => {
  const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api";

  return fetch(apiUrl + "/genres")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const res = Array.from(data.results);
      return res;
    });   
};
console.log(genres)

export function getGenres() {
  return genres().then(res => res.filter(g => g));
}
```

and updating the state of my component in here :

```
componentDidMount() {
    const genres = [{ _id: "", name: "All Genres" }, ...getGenres()];
    this.setState({ genres});

  }
```

I'm aware that probleme comes from  the fact that genres returns an object while the state should be an array but I'm not sure how to fixe it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getGenres` returns a promise, so you need to wait for it to resolve before you try to put what is returned from it in state.

```
componentDidMount() {
  getGenres().then(res => {
    const genres = [{ _id: "", name: "All Genres" }, ...res];
    this.setState({ genres });
  })
}
```